# Entity framework code first: should be used as a production technique or it's only for test purposes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

As the title says, should this technique be used only for test purposes or could it be used in programs that will be used by anyone?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: seems pretty subjective, when is anything ready for "production"?  It is a relatively new release, so it depends on what you expect of your production code.

Comment: Well I'm asking this to know if there is something from microsoft or things like that, which states "this things should be used only for testing"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good and tested and ready for any kind of testing or deployment or production purposes. Though, I would second the opinion of @Betty of not using the database dropping/recreating functionality. Since a minor glitch in the database might make you lose all your data .

I have used this in my Asp.net project which is currently online for a month or so and it's working charm. Microsoft has pulled amazing thing and you shouldn't worry about. It's a complete project, if anything only advance features will be added and nothing else.

Comment: Well you also posted about your experience, I find it really important

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend using the database dropping/recreating functionality in production as you lose your data in the process.

However the standard model -> db mapping and querying stuff is all good.

Comment: Well it's ok I don't have to use that functionality, I thought that too however

Answer (score 2):

It's a fully featured, tested release, not a CTP or beta. Why wouldn't it be ready to use in a production environment? Whether you *want to* use it in a production environment is entirely up to you and your team.

Comment: I asked this because I'm not sure if it's suggested creating the database with "your hands" rather than let C# create it for you. I'm not afraid of beta/ctp things. Also is a new approach so I'm asking this if hopefully someone has already used it can give me some suggestions